# Threads and locks when necessary?

Tags: python

Say I have an empty multidimensional list `data = [[], []]` and a function which appends values to one of the sublists:

```
def append(data):
   #appending values to data
```

I start two threads, each appending data to one of the respective sublists:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target = append, args = [data[0]])
t2 = threading.Thread(target = append, args = [data[1]])
```

Do I have to worry that this is going to mess things up? I'm new to threading and I read that you have to use locks because there can be a problem when threads try to access a variable at the same time. But I haven't see any problem with my code. Is it okay in this case because the threads access different sub-arrays?

Comment: No, you pass two separate lists into separate threads, there's no problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using different lists, you won't have an issue at all.

In fact, if all you're doing is appending, and don't mind the order, you may even use the same list and append to it from different threads.

The default Python implementation, CPython, has a GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). Apart from memory management, the GIL makes sure single operations on pure mutable builtin primitives, such as dict, list and set, will cause no interference.

Comment: Of course you still have to be aware of what a single operation is. For instance augmented operatiors such as `+=` are 3 operations: load, do the operation, store, and are not atomic.

Comment: @tdelaney specifically in case of lists, the only type of the 3 which has +=, what you said is not true as += is translated to `.extend()` and if the extension receives primitives (iteration is not implemented in Python but in C), then it's atomic. What you said is relevant mostly for immutable types if the same variable is shared.

Comment: @Bharel - no, the compiler doesn't know anything about object types or mutable/immutable. It generates 3 instructions LOAD/INPLACE_ADD/STORE which gives two opportunities for a thread switch between op codes. The load may be an immutable int or a mutable list, the compiler doesn't know. Immutability is not a language construct, its enforced by the object itself. This 3 step process lets an object decide whether it wants to update itself and return self, or create a new object and return that.

Comment: @Bharel - so even though list iadd is translated to extend, its done in the INPLACE_ADD and the result is stored back into the original variable in the next op code.

Comment: @tdelaney True, but then again the result of iadd is the list itself. If you'll do it twice at the same time, nothing bad will happen. So while the storing, loading, and operation won't occur at once, the result will not matter and still be accurate and threadsafe. Point being, it won't be atomic per-se but will be completely threadsafe because of the actual action and way it works.

Comment: The only time it will actually matter is if the variable is changed to a different object between the add and store, in which case it will override the new object with the list. But it won't collide if you'll do += from 2 different threads at the same time on the same list, which is close to the OP's intention on using append.